# Anaconda Jupyter "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically."

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I launch Jupyter from Anaconda navigator, I download Anaconda application and create a new environment named 'tf' for tensorflow by following this video: [How to install Tensorflow and Keras using Anaconda Navigator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V9cDjjRXS08)
Then I want to repeat this tutorial [Basic classification: Classify images of clothing](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification) from Tensorflow office website, I copy and paste each cell one by one and when I run this cell, it has a warning message said "**The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.**"

```
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images,  test_labels, verbose=2)

print('\nTest accuracy:', test_acc)
```

I have no idea how to fix that, I search some answer said that is because run out of memory, but I am wondering is the code run in Jupyter using my laptop's memory? I am using a 128G old Macbook pro and I am not very confidence about its memory..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to load a model that doesn't fit in your RAM memory. Thus, the kernel dies.

Your old MacBook pro has 4Gb of RAM. According to the link you shared, you're trying to load this model:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])
```

Assuming you're using `float32` tensors, this is the amount of data you're trying to load: `28 x 28 x 128 x 10 = 1003520` parameters times 4 bytes, that is, `4014080 bytes` or `3920Mb`. As your laptop needs some memory to work, you don't have memory enough to load this model.

Try to reduce the number of neurons or resize the image.

Comment: Thank you and I think you are correct, I change ```keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),``` to ```keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu'),``` and it seems work, but the accuracy is too small. I will try to figure it tomorrow, thank you very much for your valuable time.

Comment: The accuracy is small because it's just one neuron. You said you're learning, so in the future, you're going to understand the reason. For now, if you remove this line ` keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')`, you're gonna have an accuracy a little bit higher.